# At which point does a Model knows which connection to use

Tags: laravel

In Laravel doing `User::all()` gets you all users. How does the Model know which database to use? I am aware that it is written in the config but where is it read from teh config?

Model gets it from its QueryBuilder that gets it passed in when constructed. But I couldnt find any Code where a Builder is constructed or where the needed data is read from the config.

Can you point me to the right place?

Answer (score 1):

The config for the database connection can be found in `config/database.php`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#introduction

In this file you will see that it will get environment variables from the `.env` file in the root of your project

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration

--

Notable values in `config/database.php` are:

`'default'` - the default connection to use, e.g. mysql

`'connections'` - the configuration for a type of connection, e.g. mysql connection details including host, port, database name and credentials

Comment: Thats not what I was asking. I am aware, that this is all written in the config. My question is at which point this is all read from teh config on order to construct a new Connection object and with that a new Builder